# Copy attributes less than value

Tags: arrays, r, operators

I have an array AGE and I want to copy all ages less thank 30 to new array a1.
I tried below code:

```
age <- c(23,24,26,27,35,42,45,49,50,52,56,56,57,59,60,61,63,64)
a1 <- age<30
a1
```

OUTPUT:

> TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE

I wish to get actual values and not True or false

Comment: a1 <- age[age<30]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`age<30` is an expression returning a `logical` vector. It's why you have a sequence of TRUE and FALSE value.

Your next step is to use this sequence to *index* the original array. For example, you can index your array with integers:

```
a1 <- age[c(1,3,5)]
a1
[1] 23 26 35
```

So you can do the same with boolean values. If the boolean value is TRUE then you take the value, if it's not, you don't take the value:

```
a1 <- age<30
age[a1]
[1] 23 24 26 27
```

And it's exactly what you wanted. Now search on the net for  "*R subsetting vectors and matrices*". It's a large and fascinating topic which shows how powerful R can be.
You can also get useful information in the R manual. From R, call the function `help.start()` to open the manual in your web browser.
Go to section *2.7 Index vectors; selecting and modifying subsets of a data set* for detailed information.

Comment: Instead of suggesting a search on the internet, typical advice is `help.start()` and pick a manual.